# How do I change the value of an html button through PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'd like to change the value of the html button but this keeps showing plain text why?

```
<input type="submit" value="<? $button_value ?>">
```

Comment: Unless short tags are enabled, use `<?php echo $button_value; ?>`, which also assumes your page is being processed by PHP.

Comment: And *if* short tags are enabled, use `<?=$button_value ?>` (the `=` is missing).

Comment: Your `<?` translates to `<?php` and not an echo `<?=` ; **IF** short tags are on.

Comment: im guessing it's not on a *.php page, and Apache is not configured to parse the page

Answer (score 6):

`<input type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_value; ?>">`

try this